# CSS div responsive next to non-responsive

Tags: html, css

I wish to have two containers next to each other. The other one would contain a linearly aligned list of elements one after another. The other one would contain just a button.

> [ [...][...][...] ] [button]

I'd like to have the left container responsive whereas the button should have a non changing width. And in all cases they have to remain on the same line and the button is not allowed to fall under the other element.

However I'm failing to achieve this. I found a lot of examples of how to do this the way around, that the button would be on the other side, but to have them this way it seems much more tricky!

Here's an example of what the HTML could look like:

```
<div class="left">
    <p>In case we are</p>
    <p>too long</p>
    <p>one will be removed due</p>
    <p>to overflow!</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

One more thing is that I would like the Button to be on the complete right of the screen. Not so that it's just an extension for the first element. Meaning that class left would have margin-left: 0px; and class right margin-right: 0px; right: 0;.

I wish this is not a duplicate, but I couldn't find a working example for my case. But many for doing it exactly the way around.

**EDIT**
Here's my .css code right now in case somebody wants to have a look what I've been messing up there.

```
.right {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3px;
    right: 0;
}
.left {
    margin-top: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But yeah, this has the issue that even that the elements find the right places in the beginning, at some point they start to overlap because of the content inside the left element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: .25em
}
.left p {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey
}
.right {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <p>In case we are</p>
    <p>too long</p>
    <p>one will be removed due</p>
    <p>to overflow!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't familiar with flex boxes before, they seem like a really good tool for building layouts. They also seem relatively safe for all browser types and devices. This helps me a lot, thank you once more!